# Steps involved in profiling java applications

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Please explain about the steps involved in profiling a JAVA application? This is irrespective of what ever profiling tools that is used. What are the best practices and steps involved in profiling the java applications?
Experts, any links or documents are really appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Thanks. The thing I want to know is there are so many profilers available but when we profile a Java applications for OutOfMemory or Memoryleaks , etc . What are the steps we need to go through in profiling the application. Let say I am using VisualVM which does have a profiler , I am getting an OutOfMemory Error in my application my application so huge that I don't know where exactly is the problem even the logger is of no use (just for assumption). In such case how we can figure out where exactly is the problem by using the profiler tool like VisualVM? And what are the steps we need to look into ? Whether we can directly use the CPU and Memory profiling or still we need to go and get the thread dump and analyse it , then create a Heap dump analyze it and then go for a CPU and Memory profiling? I am little confused here. Hence please point me to the right direction as well as the steps involved in profiling a JAVA application to find the memory leaks. Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question is too generic, please explain your problem.

Comment: OP is SO member for 1 year, 9 months :)

Comment: Membership length alone doesn't mean he's not a newbie, though perhaps Jigar should have said "Welcome *back* to StackOverflow".

Comment: A Google search for "profiling java applications" yields useful results ...

Comment: STOP slaughtering people for asking questions that you dont like people! Why the downvotes??

Comment: @O.D this question is only marginally related to coding, tagged wrong and extremely general. also, 'point me to the right direction' reads like "please send me a link to google". in my opinion this fits the description in the faq which questions shouldn't be asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why you need to profile your application you have to decide what filters you will need, as mentioned inthe comments the question is very general, you should provide some more percise information to get some help hier.

Try the following link (in Eclipse):

[An introduction to profiling Java applications](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html)

And check [this List](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) or Open source java profilers

Answer (score 0):

i have used JProfiler and yourkit but i am not satisfied with output for actual performance tuning. currently we have been switched to [java melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/). This not only help performance optimization in dev but also in production system. Java melody is very easy to integrate and configure and in production you can enable or disable by just updating web.xml

Answer (score 0):

This series of articles should give you a good idea on how you go about serious performance investigation of a relatively complex Java application.

http://www.jinspired.com/solutions/case-studies/scala-compiler